# Oracle CEP on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, oracle, configuration, complex-event-processing

I went to run my application on Eclipse IDE 3.7 using an Oracle Complex event processing server 11.1, it works with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10, the problem is that it doesn't work Oracle Lunix 6. I am not familiar with this OS, I need your help please to find a solution for this problem. Thanks a lot.
Tarek.

Comment: We need more information than 'it doesn't work'. What goes wrong? What errors do you get?

Comment: the eroor message is: "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ETL-SERVER: ETL-SERVER". ETL-SERVER is localhost name,the system in use is 64 bits. the java version is openjdk 1.6.0.